# tkinter Entry <Return> event doesn't execute function

Tags: python

I'm just starting learning python and I tried to make Rock, Paper, Scissors game. However when I press Enter after filling my username - it can't execute the function that's the same func the 'Play' button executes.

```
def start_game():
    controller.set_user_name(input_name.get())
    frame.destroy()
    logo_label.destroy()
    name.destroy()
    input_name.destroy()
    sub.destroy()
    main_game_window()
```

```
input_name=Entry(root,font='arial 10 bold')
input_name.bind('<Return>',start_game)  
input_name.place(x=275,y=290)

sub=Button(root,text="Let's Play",font='lucida 10 bold',bg='black',fg='white',command=start_game)
sub.place(x=305,y=350)
```

Also the 'computer' picks only once, although it's set to pick random on every round. Will be thankfull if someone gives me an advice.

```
import random
choices = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')

class Player:
    def __init__(self,name='Computer',score=0, choice=random.choice(choices)):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.choice = choice
        
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score
    
    def increase_score(self):
        self.score += 1
        
    def set_choice(self, choice=random.choice(choices)):
        self.choice = choice
        
    def get_choice(self):
        return self.choice
```

https://github.com/ITWebFun/rock-paper-scissors.git

For the entry, although I'm not passing an argument it gives me an error

```
File "C:\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: start_game() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add ‘event’ as a parameter in your start_game() function. Modified code:

```
def start_game(event=None):
    controller.set_user_name(input_name.get())
    frame.destroy()
    logo_label.destroy()
    name.destroy()
    input_name.destroy()
    sub.destroy()
    main_game_window()
```

Then the start_game() function will be able to accept the enter key command. We set the default value of the event parameter to zero, so that the Button widget can access the function too.

Comment: Any suggestions for the class why the set_choice optional parameter doesn't work?
def set_choice(self, choice=random.choice(choices)):
        self.choice = choice